# Parsing a Youtube API Date in Java

Tags: java, youtube

What is the format of uploaded date of youtube api I can use in SimpleDateFormat?

example "`2013-03-31T16:46:38.000Z`"

P.S. solution was found `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`

thanks

Comment: SimpleDateFormat will be able to parse just about any date string you throw at it.  You only have to tell it the format in which to expect it.  Also, Apache Commons Lang has some Date parsing abilities, I believe, that might simplify things.

Comment: I also thought so, but 
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-03-31T16:46:38.000Z"

Answer (score 3):

It is a [ISO 8061 date time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Actually, at least in Java8 it's very simple to parse that one as there is a predefined `DateTimeFormatter`. Here a small unit test as demonstration:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class DateTimeFormatterTest {

    @Test
    public void testIsoDateTimeParse() throws Exception {
        // when
        final ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2013-03-31T16:46:38.000Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);

        // then
        assertEquals(2013, dateTime.getYear());
        assertEquals(3, dateTime.getMonthValue());
        assertEquals(31, dateTime.getDayOfMonth());
        assertEquals(16, dateTime.getHour());
        assertEquals(46, dateTime.getMinute());
        assertEquals(38, dateTime.getSecond());
        assertEquals(ZoneOffset.UTC, dateTime.getZone());
    }
}
```

Prior to Java8, I would take a look at [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date) and definitley default to using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) with sth. like:

```
final org.joda.time.DateTime dateTime = new org.joda.time.DateTime.parse("2013-03-31T16:46:38.000Z");
```

BTW, don't use `new DateTime("2013-03-31T16:46:38.000Z")` as it will use your default time zone, which is probably not what you want.